# Disable the mouse in a video?

Tags: html, video-streaming, mouse

Is there a code wich you can use to disable your whole mouse.
I have been searching for codes to do dis but they won't work.
I have a page with a video on it but you can pause it. thats's why i want to disable the mouse.

If there is another way for preventing my video getting paused that would also be nice to hear.

Comment: Put an object like a div over it with z-index

Comment: Thanks Pieter, it was an good idea

Answer (score 0):

Add pointer-events: none; to the css of that element.
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/